# Getting return status for each object inserted by insertbatch command

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using C# drivers for Mongo Db.
I would like to use the insertbatch command passing it a list of objects (IList).
For each object inserted I would like to know the result status (if it was inserted successfully or not).  I saw that the insertbatch returns only one SafeModeResult object for each 16MB chunk that it insert.
What is the best approach for me, if I want  to use the insertbatch command and getting return status for each object that I insert?

The same question follows for remove elements from a collection using a query that returns more than one element.  I would like to know for each element that I remove, if it was removed successfully or not.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure SafeMode is on. The easiest way is to set SafeMode on in the connection string:

var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost/?safe=true";

If InsertBatch completes without throwing an exception you know that all documents were inserted without error.

If InsertBatch throws an exception then it failed partway through the batch. Unfortunately the server does not report how far into the batch it got before failing, and you will have query the database to see if a particular document got inserted or not.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly for Remove, if Remove completes without throwing an exception then you know that all  matching documents were successfully removed.

Remove throws an exception if the server reported an error (assuming SafeMode is on). However, the server doesn't report whether it removed any documents or not. Calling Find with the same query you passed to Remove will retrieve all the documents that were not deleted.